# How to zip selected files? not all the files in a directory in c#

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, zip

I want to zip some files in a directory. I have googled a lot but i always saw examples about zipping a directory (all files in directory) by the code below:

```
string startPath = @subPath;

string zipPath = @"C:\result.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

I am referencing  `System.IO.Compression.Filesystem.dll`

This code zips all the files in the directory referenced by startPath.

I tried  ZipArchive class for compressing but it compress file with directories on its path. For example,
assume i want to zip "a.txt" located at "C:\directories\Graphics\a.txt". The zip file contains directories "directories" and "Graphics" and into these directories the file "a.txt". It is not a good solution to cut files then erase the directories and paste again since i am working on big size data.

How can I zip only some of files at a directory?

How can I zip some files that are located in different directories?

I am looking up the subject for 2 days. Is it a kind of constraint in .Net?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ZipArchive class, first create it and then - once created you just add ZipArchiveEntry objects into the archive. Each of the ZipArchiveEntry objects represents a single file that you will add to the archive.

Some tips:
You can find more info and a sample of how this could be done on MSDN, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: It is working i can zip selected files but now, zipfile contains directories of selected files,too. For example assume i want to zip   "a.txt" located at "C:\\directories\\Graphics\\a.txt". The zip file contains  directories "directories" and "Graphics" and into these directories the file "a.txt".   It is not a good solution to cut the files and erase directoires and paste the files again. What can be done for the problem?

Comment: @ersingüreli i know it's a bit late, but i'm guessing it has to do with [how you create the archive entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.createentry?view=net-5.0): `archive.CreateEntry("Are/You/Including/Source/Paths?.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an exact solution but should work for your scenario. I'll give you the steps :

> 1. Create a Temporary Directory
> 2. Read and copy your Selected files into the Temporary directory. This applies to your second scenario as well.
> 3. Zip the temporary directory
> 4. Delete Temporary Directory after you are done

Comment: Don't forget to delete the temp directory after zip ;)

Comment: Thanks for advice you Codeek ,too :) . Files have huge size, and i have time constraint. It is not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `File.Copy` to copy all your desired files to a temporary directory, then zip them all from there and delete the temporary directory once the zip operation has finished.

Comment: Thanks for advice but files i am working on have huge size, it takes mcuh time.