# c# Adding Directory.GetFiles to Zip File

Tags: c#, file, zip

I have lots of logs in a folder, I would like to **only grab files that have todays date** and put them in the zip file.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Specify todays date
    DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Today;

    //Create a zip file with the name logs + todays date
    string zipPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ZIP\logs" + todaysDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".zip";
    string myPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\LOG SEARCH";

    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*" + todaysDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

How do I zip `files` ?

Comment: no i need for this to happen in `foreach` I am getting the list of files, that I need now I just need to add them to the zip file.

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22339337/424129 -- see the comments as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you can do is create a temporary folder and then add each file that matches the current date in it. Once that's done you can `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` and then delete the temporary folder

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Today;

//Create a zip file with the name logs + todays date
string zipPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ZIP\logs" + todaysDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".zip";
string myPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\LOG SEARCH";

string tempPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ZIP\logs" + todaysDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*" + todaysDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*");

Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Copy(file, tempPath + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
}

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempPath, zipPath);

Directory.Delete(tempPath, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use System.IO.Compression;
and use

```
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(myPath, zipPath);
```

Comment: this will grab all the files in the directory, I only want specific ones

Comment: Probably you looking for :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550413/how-to-zip-selected-files-not-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Comment: this is a different solution. I need to recreated my whole program